# How to get the distinct id using the same column twice in SQL

Tags: sql

[image]

I have the following issue. I have a `user_id` column and an `attribute_id`column and I want to get the users id that has the `attribute_id` 1 and 4.

In this case, the result would be one single column with the `user_id` 1 and 35, once they both have the `attribute id` 1 and 4.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this:

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM table_name
WHERE attribute_id IN (1, 4)
GROUP BY user_id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT attribute_id) = 2;
```

Comment: That works, but I tried to understand why and still not sure. Can you clarify what is happening in this query?

Comment: In `WHERE`, the query find all user have attribute_id 1 and 4, to get result X. And in the `GROUP BY .... HAVING`, it count the distinct `attribute_id` in X in case we have duplicate `attribute_id` for one `user_id`. If table has constraint to ensure no duplication of `attribute_id` for each `user_id` then you could omit `DISTINCT` in query.

Answer (score 0):

Really depends on your data, but if you have only 1s and 4s, you can do it like this:

```
with users as
(
select '62' as userid,  1 as attributeid union
select '63' as userid,  1 as attributeid union
select '63' as userid,  1 as attributeid union
select '1' as userid,  1 as attributeid union
select '35' as userid,  1 as attributeid union
select '35' as userid,  4 as attributeid union
select '1' as userid,  4 as attributeid
)
select userid from users group by userid having sum(distinct attributeid) = 5;
```

If you can also have 2 and 3 as attributeid (so you get also 5), you can use this:

```
with users as
(
select '62' as userid,  1 as attributeid union
select '63' as userid,  1 as attributeid union
select '63' as userid,  1 as attributeid union
select '1' as userid,  1 as attributeid union
select '35' as userid,  1 as attributeid union
select '35' as userid,  4 as attributeid union
select '1' as userid,  4 as attributeid
)
select u1.userid from users u1
    inner join users u4 on u1.userid = u4.userid
                        and u1.attributeid = 1 
                        and u4.attributeid = 4;
```